# React native add listener on Animated.add value

Tags: react-native

I have several animated value and I would like to do things based on their sum (`Animated.add`).

Here is minimal working example (with the [complete version available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-listeners-on-animated-add-values-hlunjp?file=/src/App.js)). In the following I add a listener on the Animated value `scroll` and also on the sum `doubleScroll`, all logs concerning `scroll` are printed as expected, but none of the `doubleScroll` update appears to be triggering its listener.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Animated, Text, View } from "react-native";


function App() {
  const scroll = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const scrollEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: scroll.y
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    { useNativeDriver: false }
  );
  const doubleScroll = Animated.add(scroll, scroll);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listenerId = scroll.addListener((value) => {
      console.log("SCROLL:", value.y);
    });
    return () => scroll.removeListener(listenerId);
  }, [scroll]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listenerId = doubleScroll.addListener((value) => {
      console.log("SCROLL x 2:", value.y);
    });
    return () => doubleScroll.removeListener(listenerId);
  }, [doubleScroll]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.ScrollView onScroll={scrollEvent}>
        <Text>...</Text>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems related to this (even though it is pretty old now) : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12620